# plot if col A has substring

Tags: gnuplot

I need to do this in gnuplot:

```
plot 1:4 where col 2=="P1", col 3=="3", col 1 has substring "blur1"
```

Heres a dataset:

```
col_1          col_2        col_3    col_4
gcc.blur1.O0   P1           3        10.5
icc.blur1.O2   P2           5        9.8
gcc.blur2.O3   P2           3        8.9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically you can do it using external script, but it is still unclear how you can plot this data using the 1st and 4th column (1st column is string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you need to use an external script to check for substrings. Something like awk and use

```
plot "< awk '{...awk commands...}' input.dat"
```

If you just want to test col_2 for P1 you can do it in gnuplot via

```
f(x,y)= (x eq "P1"? y : 1/0)

plot "input.dat" u 3:(f(strcol(2),$4))
```

strcol(n) gets the n-ths column as a string. "eq" can be used to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

Such a simple check can be done with gnuplot's `strstrt` function. It returns the index of the first character found, or 0 if the substring wasn't found:

```
strstrt(strcol(3), 'blur1') > 0
```

So, your plot command can look like

```
matchesLine(col1, col2, col3) = strstrt(strcol(1), col1) > 0 && strcol(2) eq col2 && strcol(3) eq col3
plot 'file' using (matchesLine("blur1", "P1", "3") ? $1 : 1/0):4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact position of the substring in advance, you can try to check for equality on that portion like this:

```
strcol(1)[5:9] eq 'blur1'
```

ps.: Here are some handy examples for dealing with strings in gnuplot:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/stringvar.html