# Modiying string input from csv to determine the leading sign

Tags: plot, substring, gnuplot

I have csv-output from another program like this:

```
1.0s,34.56a
3.0s,352.12a
5.0s,1995.34b
```

The first column contains x-values (the `s` can be neglected) while the second column contains y-values. Using Gnuplot 5 it is possible to simply plot the values, however, I need to determine the leading sign of each value in the second column (all values followed by `a` should be positive, all values followed by `b` should be negative).

While the determination of the sign should be easy like described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359808/if-control-sequence-under-gnuplot), I'm struggling to split each y-value dynamically. According to the Gnuplot manual, using a substring should be possible but I can't figure out how to tell the substring to only contain the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last character of a string `s`, use

```
s[strlen(s):]
```

To parse your data file correctly, use the following:

```
set datafile separator ','
parse(s) = (s[strlen(s):] eq "b" ? -1 : 1) * real(s[:strlen(s)-1])
plot 'data.dat' using 1:(parse(strcol(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it, posting my solution for others. My solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130670/gnuplot-extract-x-values-from-string-in-data) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615843/plot-if-col-a-has-substring).

I created a new function `customydata(s)=(s[strlen(s):*])` which returns the last character of a string.

The plot command simply is `plot 'heelingdata.dat' u 1:(customydata(strcol(2)) eq 'a' ? (-1)*$2 : $2) w lp` where I insert my string into the abovementioned function and check if it's is `a`.